# FOS UserBundle FormType, Entity, RegistrationFormType

Tags: php, symfony, entity, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'm very new of Symfony and I have a doubt that I can't solve by myself.
I made a web application with Symfony2, and I use the vendor FOS UserBundle and PUGXMultiUserBundle.
In this application there are three files:

```
RegistrationUserFormType.php
ProfileUserFormType.php
Entity/User.php
```

Why I need three files? Shouldn't be enough to have the entity for the user and the RegistrationUserFormType associated?
What is the ProfileUserFormType?

Sorry for the dummy question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with PUGXMultiUserBundle, but I can guess that ProfileUserFormType is used to manage *User Profile* data which won't necessarily have the same fields as the registration one.

Comment: Actually there are also in the FOSUser Bundle, [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Form/Type)

Comment: Well yes, Registration one is the form which is shown on registration page, and the profile one - on profile page.